# Is there a nicer way to write a self referential let expression

Tags: haskell

i.e. can we write the following more concisely?

```hs
bar in_env a = let out_env = foo in_env (R a out_env) in out_env
```

I want to write it something like

```hs
bar in_env a = foo in_env (R a ??)
```

But maybe it isn't possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, rewrite it like this, so that you'll be able to easily eta-reduce away `out_env` in the next step:

```
bar in_env a = let out_env = foo in_env . R a $ out_env in out_env
```

Then, use the fact that recursive `let` is equivalent to `fix`:

```
import Data.Function (fix)
bar in_env a = fix $ foo in_env . R a
```

Comment: This is literally exactly the thing I was looking for thanks!